# React JSS style global

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I'm using [React-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss) to set up global style. For example:

```
export default {
  '@global': {
    body: {
      margin: 0,
      fontFamily: '"Lobster", cursive, Roboto, "sans-serif"',
    },
  },
};
```

Code above works for me but when I want to style for css  like this it not working.

```
export default {

 '@global': {
    body: ...,
    '& *:before, & *:after': {
      boxSizing: 'border-box',
    },
  },
};
```

I've searched on their github issues, on google, on their docs but still not find any answer for this question. Pls help me, thank you guys

Comment: it actually isn't clear what the issue you're having is.  can you clarify "it not working", provide usage of the global declarations. rather, the 'injections' of the stylesheet for this global stylesheet.

Comment: the issue that I just want to set style global for *:after and *:before but code above not working for me.